# Modify SQL query to get all users?

Tags: mysql

I currently have this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (o.customer_id), count( o.id ) AS orders, c.* 
FROM `order` AS o LEFT JOIN customer AS c ON o.customer_id = c.id 
GROUP BY customer_id
```

What it does is it returns all customers that have made an order and counts the number of orders each customer has made.

What I need to do is modify this query so it also returns those customers who haven't made an order. Do you have any idea how this would be done?

I tried to reverse the query but this didn't do the trick..

```
SELECT DISTINCT (o.customer_id), count( o.id ) AS orders, c.* 
FROM customer AS c LEFT JOIN order AS o ON o.customer_id = c.id 
GROUP BY o.customer_id
```

Comment: u already write `DISTINCT (o.customer_id)` then what is the need of
`GROUP BY customer_id`

Comment: the distinct does nothing in this case ..

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT o.customer_id, sum( case when o.id is not null then 1 else 0 end ) AS orders, c.* 
FROM customer  c
LEFT JOIN order o ON o.customer_id = c.id GROUP BY customer_id
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (o.customer_id), count( o.id ) AS orders, c.* 
    FROM `order` AS o 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN customer AS c ON o.customer_id = c.id GROUP BY customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.customer_id, c.* 
FROM customer AS c LEFT JOIN order AS o ON o.customer_id = c.id 
WHERE o.id IS NULL
GROUP BY o.customer_id
```

You can also skip the "GROUP BY" clause because when the orders side is NULL, there is always only one row for the customer:

```
SELECT o.customer_id, c.* 
FROM customer AS c LEFT JOIN order AS o ON o.customer_id = c.id 
WHERE o.id IS NULL
```